# OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

At the moment I'm taking a look into Spring Boot 2, OAuth2 and single sign on. I'm running a sample project but am getting:

ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter

I'm unable to located the Maven dependency that will give me this [class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.html).

I've tried every combination of spring-security core, starter etc.

Below is my Pom as is:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>-->

</dependencies>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in nailing down the correct dependencies.

Comment: Using eclipse? go to maven dependencies -> spring-security-oauth2 jar and check whether this file(`OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class`) is present. If not, it might be a version issue

Comment: @theLearner Have opened version 2.2.1-RELEASE with winzip and that class is missing. Looking at the tagged javadoc in the above, the release version since is 5.0 - making me think that it should be part of spring security 5. This isn't the case when opening that jar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12654) with Spring for this issue. While it's an ongoing conversation, I did resolve the missing dependency. Just include:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```